# Skill Ranks, I need more

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Is there a way I can put more skill ranks into intimidate than my level would normally allow? I seek to have +3 into intimidate at level 1 so I can immediately grab Boar Style.

Comment: Answer in answers, not comments.

Comment: [Related] [What's the most effective way to maximize skills as a character of any class?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63277)

Comment: If you need Boar Style, you can get it at first level with the Master of Many Styles(Monk) or Unarmed Fighter(Fighter) archetypes as both allow you to ignore the prerequisites of style feats,

Comment: I was trying to be a brawler, however I'll cope with Monk, Master of Many Styles it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to have more ranks in a skill than your character has hit dice:

> Acquiring Skills
>
> Each level, your character gains a number of skill ranks dependent
>   upon your class plus your Intelligence modifier. Investing a rank in a
>   skill represents a measure of training in that skill. **You can never
>   have more ranks in a skill than your total number of Hit Dice.**

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Acquiring-Skills

Comment: So there is no other way for me to gain skill ranks passed my level?

Comment: @TriforceGuardian correct. But under certain circumstances, there are ways to ignore feat prereqs. For an example, take a look at Guest's comment on your question.